# Can I convert symbols (!@#) to numbers (123) on Microsoft or Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a large number of files that are showing on symbols (!@##$$@#%@#). I need to convert them to numbers (12334423523).

Comment: I can suggest you VBA macro will convert each character (including Alphabets & Numbers) to its ASCII equivalent. If this works for you then please [Edit] your post & add that VBA macro will be accepted also Add TAG `VBA` to the question.

Comment: Perhaps when you open the file, you can specify the proper encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`SUBSTITUTE`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/substitute-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332) to replace texts

> =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, "!", "1"), "@", "2"), "#", "3"), "$", "4"), "%", "5"), "^", "6"), "&", "7"), "*", "8"), "(", "9"), ")", "0")

But that's not a good way to replace text in all the documents. In that case use a macro instead

Comment: This is good one but is all around the Characters OP has show as sample data,, I think the best is ASCII conversion !!